# ModelForm returning field is required, not saving to sqliteDB

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

Every time I attempt to save my form, my template returns "This Field is required". The issue is I have filled out that field, it is the only field I need to fill out.. I am slightly frustrated and I have a feeling that this forum is going to tear me apart for asking this, but can someone take a look at it and tell me what I am doing wrong. Thank you in advance!

models.py

```
class TimeClockIN(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    driver_number = models.IntegerField(max_length=8)   
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, blank=True)
```

forms.py

```
class ClockInForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = models.TimeClockIN
        fields = [
           'driver_number',

       ]
```

views.py:

```
def clock_in_view(request):
    form = forms.ClockInForm()
    pull_all = Driver.objects.all()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ClockInForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            for driver in pull_all:
                if request in driver.driver_number:
                    time_in_instance = form.save(commit=False)
                    time_in_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
                    time_in_instance.save()
                    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                        "Clocked IN")
                    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('clockin'))
            else:
                form = forms.ClockInForm()




    return render(request, 'clockinform.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve at this line -> if request in driver.driver_number <- ? you can't do that

Comment: I am trying to check to see if the input from html matches a driver number in the DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to have the driver_number field in the TimeClockIN model (it already exists in the driver field). You can create a normal django form where you retrieve the driver_number. Afterwards, try to get the driver from the db and if it exists, create a new TimeClockIN instance with the coresponding data and save it. This assumes that each driver_number is unique among Drivers.

If you later need to get the driver_number from the TimeClockIN model, you just follow the driver foreign key and get it from there.

Model:

```
class TimeClockIN(models.Model):
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField()
    driver = models.ForeignKey(Driver, blank=True)
```

Form:

```
class ClockInForm(forms.Form):
    driver_number = forms.IntegerField(required=True, max_length=8)
```

View:

```
def clock_in_view(request):
    form = forms.ClockInForm()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ClockInForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            try: 
                driver = Driver.objects.get(driver_number=form.cleaned_data['driver_number'])
                time_in_instance = TimeClockIN()
                time_in_instance.timestamp = timezone.now()
                time_in_instance.driver = driver
                time_in_instance.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS,
                                    "Clocked IN")
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('clockin'))
            except Driver.DoesNotExist:
                form = forms.ClockInForm()
    return render(request, 'clockinform.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: I have the foreign key pointing back to Driver because that is where all the Driver numbers are located at

Comment: Also the form still wont submit, It returns "This field is required"

Comment: @Leroy_Brown updated example with a slightly different structure

Comment: When I get back to my computer I will check it out. Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: When I change the .GET to a .POST it returns a `NAME ERROR: global name 'timezone' is not defined`

Comment: @Leroy_Brown that means that you didn't impor the timezone; add this at the top of the file : from django.utils import timezone

Comment: Thanks, it works, however it is giving me the driverID which works but I would prefer the driver name, how can I do that?

Comment: @Leroy_Brown don't understand your question..and where do you want to use the driver name? It seems this is another question that should be posted. If this answer works for your initial question, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: okay thank you for you help I will post a link to the new question in this feed.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong thing to the form instantiation.

```
form = forms.ClockInForm(request.POST)
```

Comment: Understood, however when I make that change it is stating that `Type Error argument of type 'int' is not iterable`  however I am checking my form input as an integer to another integer field. why would I get this error?

Comment: Because you're doing `if request in driver.driver_number`; a request can't be in a number.

Comment: so you are saying I need to add another instance as in  `def clock_in_view(request, driver_number): ` ?

Comment: No, I didn't say anything like that at all.